# Sending objects as parameters to forked nodejs processes

Tags: node.js

Having `fork('./MyProcess.js',['foo']);` in the main process and `console.log(process.argv[2]);` in the forked process will log *foo* to my console.

However, `fork('./MyProcess.js',[{myProp : 'bar'}]);` in the main process and `console.log(process.argv[2]); console.log(process.argv[2].myProp);` in the forked process will log *[object Object]* (as expected) but *undefined* for the second log.

Why is this, and what should I do to get the desired behavior?

Comment: [`child_process.fork`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) expects an array of strings for `args`, yet you provided an array containing an object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pass object(json) to child process through commadline arguments is not a good idea, command arguments need escape first(not easy). You have some choice:

1. hex encode the json then pass to child process, this works but your child process interface is bad.
2. save json to a file, pass the file path instead.
3. pass the json to child process through stdin.
4. send the json as message to child process, see https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_send_message_sendhandle_options_callback

Comment: Thanks, I'll send it as a message as I'm already doing that in some other scenarios.

Comment: correct link for item number 4 https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_send_message_sendhandle_options_callback

Answer (score 4):

As stated in the documentation of [child_process.fork](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options):

> child_process.fork(modulePath[, args][, options])
>
> `args`  List of **string** arguments

By doing `fork('./MyProcess.js',[{myProp : 'bar'}])`, you are passing an object where a string was expected. The resulting behaviour might become implementation dependent, but my trial on Node.js v6.1.0 shows that the object would be converted to the string '[object Object]'. The string will not have the `myProp` property, thus yielding undefined.

The solution is to pass strings only:

```
fork('./MyProcess.js', ['bar']);
```

If you care about named parameters, simply format them appropriately (see below), then parse them with another package (such as [`yargs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs)) or a solution of your own. In this case, you could do this:

```
fork('./MyProcess.js', ['--myProp=bar']);
```

For completeness, you could have this in "MyProcess.js":

```
var argv = require('yargs').argv;
console.log('My prop is: ' + argv.myProp);
```

Comment: Why not just JSON.stringify an object? That's what I'm doing. :1

Comment: @JudeDesir That would also be possible. That however is not idiomatic for a command line interface, thus why I preferred to use yargs here. JSON, or using inter-process channels instead of command line arguments, are reasonable alternatives for passing large or complex objects.

Answer (score 1):

**Choice No.5**, It's much better to set a KEY VALUE pair in `env` option.

```
// in parent process
fork('./some.js', {
  env: Object.assign(process.env, { HELLO: 'world' })
});
// in forked process <some.js>
console.log(process.env.HELLO);
// world
```

Comment: Don't do that! https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processenv says: "Assigning a property on process.env will implicitly convert the value to a string. This behavior is deprecated. Future versions of Node.js may throw an error when the value is not a string, number, or boolean."

Answer (score 1):

You can base64 encode your object:

```
const obj = { foo: 'bar', date: new Date() };
const encoded = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(obj)).toString('base64');

fork('./MyProcess.js',[encoded]);
```

On the receiving end:

```
const data = process.argv[2];
const decoded = JSON.parse(
  Buffer.from(data, 'base64').toString('utf-8')
);
```