# passing socket.io socket to a forked node child process

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, centos7, child-process

- Centos : 7
- Node : 8.9.4
- Socket.io : 2.1.1
- Express : 4.16.3

I want to pass the SOCKET object to Node child process that I forked, but I get errors. 
Could someone explain why am I getting an error with my current code and how I can achieve sending the socket to the child process?

```
//-------------[parent.js]-------------
var child = cp.fork('../child/child.js', ['Started Child!']);

_IO.on('connection', function(_Socket){

        child.send(_Socket); // TypeError : Converting circular structure to JSON
        child.send('socket', _Socket); // TypeError : [ERR_INVALID_HANDLE_TYPE]
}); 

//-------------[child.js]-------------
process.on('message', function(socket){
        console.log(typeof socket);
});

//-------------[OR]-------------

process.on('message', function(msg, socket){
        console.log(msg);
        console.log(typeof socket);
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending objects as parameters to forked nodejs processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300556/sending-objects-as-parameters-to-forked-nodejs-processes)

Comment: My issues is different, he was trying to send via terminal parameters which he needed to send via IPC, but im already sending it via IPC but my issues is its  causing errors, and I dont know why.

Comment: Doc for sending a socket between processes is here: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_example_sending_a_socket_object.  SInce you refer to `_IO.on(...)`, I'm going to guess this is a socket.io socket.  You can't send that object.  You need to send the actual socket object (which is inside the socket.io object somewhere).  Trying to send the socket.io object will attempt to convert it to JSON (which is not what you want) and will end up with the circular structure error.  You need to send the lower level socket itself.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that when I get home but the main purpose of me trying to send the socket is I wanted to be able to communicate/emit to the socket on the client browser. I wonder if I will be able to do that still.

Comment: So apparently I learn, the reason I cant do that is because both processes dont share memory